# PHP retrieval with MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am really sorry if you find it difficult to understand. But what i am looking for is a way to stop my results from MYSQL populating outside of my div. so for example;

```php
echo "
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>

      <a href='index.php?option=User&place=quest&id=$row[id]&time=$row[time]'>


        <img src='media/quest/$row[id].jpg' height=50 width=50 onmouseover='tooltip' title='$row[description]'>


      </a>
    </td>
    <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
    <td>" . gmdate("i:s", $row['time']) . "</td>
    <td>";
```

the above code works but for example if i have 10 results they go across the page. and ignore the rules of my div.

basically what i am looking for is when 5 results populate then results move down a row. As if i add  at the end of the current code the problem goes vertically as oppose to horizontal.

![as you can see in this image the background map [so to speak] is the background of the div and there are results outside of the div. What i am looking for is a way to stop this from populating outside of the div and instead create a new row. hope this makes more sense[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCuWq.png)

Comment: please make more clear, what you want as result. if you want to populate table with 5 database rows and then have it start in the next table row, then you would have to implement a counter which adds `</tr><tr>` when it hits 5 so your next results end up in next row. obviously you can not have your `<table>` tag in your row template.

Comment: Sorry that it may not make much sense, how would i be able to add a </tr><tr> counter?

Answer (score 0):

So if you actually want to create a table with 5 results per row then assuming that `$result` is the result returned from your query, then you would go about like this:

```
echo "<table><tr>";
$count = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $count++;
    if ($count % 5) echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "
    <td>
      <a href='index.php?option=User&place=quest&id=$row[id]&time=$row[time]'>
        <img src='media/quest/$row[id].jpg' height=50 width=50 onmouseover='tooltip' title='$row[description]'>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
    <td>" . gmdate("i:s", $row['time']) . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Now this could be implemented even cleaner, but as a simple sample this should serve.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to do what i wanted from this information[had to create to variables however does the job](http://www.phpjabbers.com/php--mysql-select-data-and-split-on-pages-php25.html)

cheers guys nevertheless